# Xamarin Native, Binding actions to listview items

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I would like to ask about bindings. What is the best approach to bind some actions in listview items in ios and android using xamarin in mvvm world. As I understand, we have few approaches.

1.
For every list item we have some `Model`, and to this model we have to add some `Commands`.

For example:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public string MyName { get; set; }
    public ICommand RemoveCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Where in `ViewModel` we have `SomeInitMethod`

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items {get;set;}

    public async Task SomeInitMethod
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection(await _myApiService.FetchItemsAsync());

        foreach(var item in Items)
        {
            item.Command = new RelayCommand(RemoveItem);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveItem(ItemModel item)
    {
        Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

But I see a drawback in `SomeInitMethod` where we should set `RemoveCommand`. What if we should to set 2 or even more commands than we duplicate code in `ListItemView`(somehow we need to bind all these commands)?

2. Next approach is somehow handle events of remove/toggle buttons and others in `Listview` and then delegate this commands directly to `ViewModel`.

Example:

```
ContactsListView.ItemRemoveClicked += (ItemModel model) => ViewModel.RemoveItem
```

Advantages is: we no longer need to handle commands in ViewModel
Drawback is: we need every time to write custom ListView and support event handling in code-behind.

3. The last approach is to send `ViewModel` to `ListItem` to set `Commands`.
   Example
   somewhere we have method CreateListViewItem on the view, let's say on iOS.

> ```
> private void InitTableView() {
>     TableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(ItemViewCell.Nib, ItemViewCell.Key);
>
>     var source = new ObservableTableViewSource <ItemModel>
>     {
>         DataSource = ViewModel.Items,
>         BindCellDelegate = (cell, viewModel, index) =>
>         {
>             if (cell is ItemModel memberCell)
>             {
>                 memberCell.BindViewModel(viewModel);
>                 memberCell.RemoveItem = (item) => ViewModel.RemoveItem;
>             }
>         }
>     };
>
>     TableView.Source = source;
> }
> ```

**Advantages**: we no longer need to have `Commands` in `Model`, and we don't need to setup this `Commands` in `ViewModel`.

Possibly, drawback is that we somehow need to have ViewModel reference.

In WPF or UWP you have `DataContext`, you can binding directly to `ViewModel`.

Which approach you use, maybe I miss something, and it would be perfect if you provide some examples or thoughts.
Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question, I want to first understand what is the main action of your bound Action.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Let's imagine that if you click on item, we need to go to item details, but also we have let's say 'x' button which will remove this item in the list of the items.